# Why am i getting [object Object] javascript JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, file

Console.log(values) returns "[object Object]" instead of logging the array.

This is my code:

```
let values = {
    "coins": 0,
    "griffinFeathers": 0,
    "souvenir": 0,
    "cogs": 0,
    "cats": 0,
    "golems": 0,
    "champions": 0,
    "minotaurs": 0,
    "inquisitors": 0
}

JSON.stringify(FileLib.write("MinotaurLoot", "values.json", values));
function thing() {
    fileThing = JSON.stringify(FileLib.read("MinotaurLoot", "values.json"));
    if (griffin_thing_idk) fileThing.griffin++;    
}

console.log(values) // [object Object]
```

Comment: Do this `console.log(JSON.stringify(values))`

Comment: shouldn't you stringify content while writing ? FileLib.write("MinotaurLoot", "values.json",JSON.stringify( values))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at:

`JSON.stringify(FileLib.write("MinotaurLoot", "values.json", values));`

`JSON.stringify()` should **either** be removed as you're not storing the returned  *stringified* version of your Object anywhere **or** do something like:

```
const stringifiedValues = 
    JSON.stringify(FileLib.write("MinotaurLoot", "values.json", values));

//Now you should be able to console.log without getting [object Object]
console.log(stringifiedValues);
```

Now, the reason why you're getting `[object Object]` is due to the fact that JavaScript's default implementation of `console.log()` does not handle gracefully JavaScript Objects as they are a 'more complex' data structure than primitives like String or Number.

As pointed out by @coderpc in the comment on your question, you can access the inner contents of an object by using the `JSON.stringify()` method before wrapping it in a `console.log` statement.

Let us know if it works.